# Custom Title Bar Python

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, titlebar

i'm working tkinter , python 3.7 on Windows , wondering if there way remove tk() window border frame , title bar without using overrideredirect(1).

i have own close button , overrideredirect(1) presents me few issues can't accept:

1.gui on top

2.can't iconify deiconify properly

3. no keyboard input can't type fields
4. screen disappers when out of focus
5. there is no icon at the taskbar when overideredirect(1) is used.

i can't use attributes("-fullscreen", true) titlebar , borders remain plus i want my window to be movable so fullscreen doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

> wondering if there way remove tk() window border frame , title bar without using overrideredirect(1)

No, there is not. Using `overrideredirect` is the only way to do it.

Comment: ohh Okay thank you!! Would there be a way to solve the disappearing window when using overideredirect(1)  and window goes out of focus!!??

Comment: @NipunMittal: I think there are a few questions on this site that might address that question.